# Regarding duplicate entries from a file

Tags: awk

Is there an awk script to remove duplicate entries from a file. My file is a txt file but is very large,has 7 million rows each row containing some entries separated by tabs.
I read it through awk .I want to see if combination of two variables let say 1 and 15 is same in two rows than i want to keep only the row with there first occurence, is there a way to do it using awk script?

Comment: you said it has 7m lines, can you tell how big the file is? the size.

Comment: @Kent , it's size is 1.4 Gb

Comment: @fedorqui ,uhr... I thought in a wrong way.. you are absolutely right..... forgive me, time to coffee...

Comment: @TapanBohra try the cmd in fedorqui's comment.

Comment: `awk -F"\t" '!a[$1 FS $15]++' file` this should work for you...

Comment: @Kent , how to write this command in an awk file, sorry i am very new to awk . I want to write this in awk file because i have to extract some other columns also from this file . THis is my awk file currently.                                                     BEGIN{FS="\t"; 
      OFS="\t";
}
{
        if($16=="256" )
                print $1, $5, $10, $13, $17;
}

Comment: Since this question is closed you should ask a new one.